# How to specify the grid row height in percents?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have two rows like this:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="85.7*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="14.3*" />
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

First one is empty, the second one contains a combo box:

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" SelectedIndex="{Binding NameIndex}"/>
```

Although I specified that the second row should be only 14.3% high, both rows have the equal 50% height. Maybe I am missing some concept here?

FULL CODE:

```
     <ListViewItem>
                                <Grid>

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.857*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0.143*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Image Name="thumbImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding MainThumbImagePath}"/>

                                    <Image Name="contTitleImage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding SlideTitleImagePath}"></Image>


                                    <ComboBox  Name="Names" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="1" SelectedIndex="{Binding NameIndex}"/>


                                </Grid>
</ListViewItem>
```

Comment: `0.5*` = 50%, you are setting the height to 143% instead! Change the Height to `0.143*`.

Comment: @XAMIMAX 2 ok, I changed them to 0.857* and 0.143* but it is still the same

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue, for me it's using relative space just fine with your `14.3*`... note those are not % values, just relative spacing, so it doesn't matter whether you write `857*; 143*`, `85.7*; 14.3*` or `0.857*; 0.143*`

Comment: Rebuild your app and post your full layout. I just set the row definitions without any problem. @grek40 I just changed my row height from `0.143` to `1.43` and it does makes a difference!

Comment: @XAMlMAX thats scary, I'm getting consistent results as long as I keep the star-size and multiply both heights by the same scalar

Comment: @grek40 Are you using some sort of converter for height?

Comment: @XAMlMAX not at all. It's the painest of all plain xaml grid as only content of a window.

Comment: Please show us the full source.

Comment: @grek40 That's exactly what I am using!!! See the answer. Maybe the .NET ver is different but it shouldn't make the slightest difference!

Comment: @grek40 please see the updated code

Comment: @grek40 which still of course splits the gird in half

Comment: @XAMIMAX yes, it indeed fixed it. Thanks! I just wonder why it was affecting it?

Comment: The 2 images were overlapping anyway so you would only see one of them at a time. `ListViewItem` seems to be behaving like a `StackPanel` and only allowing the space that you need. if you have image that is 150 high then that is the space that you will get. otherwise 1 item would take all of the visible space.

Comment: @XANIMAX Yes, I see...I notice now that the image takes only first big row, and the combobox takes second small row. However, the requirement is that the picture takes entire item space and the combobox to be on top of it and cover that small portion of the picture at the bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to the comment

> However, the requirement is that the picture takes entire item space and the combobox to be on top of it and cover that small portion of the picture at the bottom

Don't play with RowSpan for such things. Instead use nested grids:

```
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="FullSpaceContent"/>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="857*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="143*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="BottomPartContentOverlappingTheImage"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Just make sure that the outer grid size fits the image and the inner grid size spans its parent size.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the `Grid` allowed to take all of the available space you should have something like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="0.143*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="0.857*"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
      <ColumnDefinition/>
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

It appears that my PC is showing different results than others. If I put `0.143*` that then is using 14.3% of available space. So if we have 2 items then the row will take 14.3% of the available 50% of the screen. However if I specify `14.3*` the it takes 143% of the available 50% of the screen.
**EDIT**
According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.gridunittype(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) star measure for grid is defined as:

> Star sizing is used to distribute available space by weighted proportions.
>   In Extensible Application Markup Language (XAML), star values are expressed as * or 2*. In the first case, the row or column would receive one times the available space; in the second case, the row or column would receive two times the available space, and so on.

Comment: `Height="14.3*"` and `Height="85.7*"` produce exactly the same result, as would `Height="143*"` and `Height="857*"`. It's only the ratio that matters.

Comment: @Clemens Not on my PC it doesn't. I had this convo with grek40. The designer shows different lines for the Grid row heights.

Comment: Not for me. And there should be an explanation in your post why it *should* matter. A link to some documentation would also be helpful.